# Apache Drill cannot read partitioned parquet files

Tags: apache-spark, azure-hdinsight, apache-drill

I have created on azure blob storage a parquet file structure with Apache Spark on HD Insight.
This is the structure:

```
 /root
      /sitename=www.site1.com
        /datekey=20160101
          log-01-file.parquet
      /sitename=www.site2.com
        /datekey=29160192
```

We want to use Apache Drill in order to run queries againts this parquet structure but we found a few issues.

When running this query

```
SELECT datekey FROM azure.root.`./root` WHERE sitename='www.mysite.com' GROUP BY datekey
```

We get this error

```
"org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: SYSTEM ERROR: NumberFormatException: www.trovaprezzi.it Fragment 2:2"
```

What could be the cause of the error?

Again, when running queries without WHERE clause seems that partitions key are seen as null values.

```
SELECT sitename, COUNT(*) as N FROM azure.root.`./root` GROUP BY sitename

|sitename|N
|NULL    |100000|
```

Does anyone experimented this issue?
Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 0):

HDInsight does not support Drill today. Hive (on Tez) should also be able to leverage the Parquet format, maybe you can try that instead?

Comment: I am using Drill on my personal laptop. On the Drill Documentation I have seen azure blob storage is supported. My Concern is that I cannot read partitions crated with spark in Drill.

Comment: Dear All, is anyone experimenting somethink similar for example on amazon S3 or local file system?

Comment: I tried also using a parquet file on my desktop pc with local drill instance but he obtain NULL values for parquet partitions (XXX=yyy directory).
Does anyone experimented this issue (better solved)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the moment of writing this post drill 1.6 seems work in this way.

Whatever partition scheme you will use DRILL will cal you parition directories structure using: dir0, dir1, etc.etc..

For instance, if we partitioned our data by hostname and date we obtain

|dir0|dir1|...
|host1|20160101|....
|host2|20160101|....